# How to enable speech in Teams Chatbot built on Bot framewok v4

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have created a Chatbot using Bot framework v4 and integrate it with Teams. I want to enable speech to text and text to speech in Teams Channel.
I already enabled STT/TTS in Webchat using webSpeechPonyfillFactory and its working fine, now i want to enable it for Teams channel, How i can do that.
I used below URL to enable Team channel.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/channel-connect-teams?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Answer (score 0):

Speech input for Bot is currently not supported. This is something we would consider but we do not have an ETA on when this will be available.